# Accidentally Uninstalled Mysql Database But I have Database Folders How do I restore the database

Tags: ubuntu, backup, database, restore

I confused our production server as staging server and accidentally uninstalled MySql. I still have the /var/lib/mysql folder intact. My server is in ubuntu 16

This is the uninstallation process that I did.
`sudo apt purge mysql*`

How do I restore the database. Kindly assist

Comment: You just install MySQL in the usual way.

Comment: i did that but upto now mysql can not start or restart

Comment: What do the logs say when you try to start MySQL? You may wish to include them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall MySQL on staging. Test the procedure there first.

Take a backup of the data. I would be very surprised if a install script deleted existing databases. But make a copy anyway just in case.

Install MySQL.

---

In the future, remove access to production when you work on test. Close all sessions to it. Perhaps remove its keys from `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar procedure in the past to test that a recovered MySQL database is working (after recovery from a failed drive). This was on Windows but it should be a similar idea. Make sure you have an extra copy of your database folders in case something goes wrong.

You'll need to install the same version of MySQL server. Downloads by version are here - https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/installer/

I am not sure what the installer will do if/when it finds existing database files in the chosen data directory. But you can specify a different data directory and finish installation. Check MySQL is running properly and run a command like SHOW DATABASES or something.

Once you have a functioning MySQL server, you can do a swap of the database files.

I followed instructions in the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098668/620054

To swap database files-

- Stop the MySQL service.
- Rename all the ib* files in the data directory to put "FRESHINSTALL"
  at the beginning or something similar.
- Copy files from your original
  data directory (ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ib_buffer_pool if
  exists) as well as any sub-directories for your databases (with frm
  files) into the new installation's data directory. Don't copy over
  directories for system databases mysql and performance_schema. Only
  copy your databases.
- Check the size of your ib_logfile0 file. If it
  is bigger than default (48M for 48 MB I think), you will need to
  adjust the MySQL config to set `innodb_log_file_size=[actual size of iblogfile0]`
- Run MySQL in recovery mode with the command like the following: `mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server x.x\my.ini" --standalone --console --innodb_force_recovery=6` (change path to config file as needed)
- Start the MySQL service.
- Check that your databases show up and run some test queries.

If that's all working, you'll want to do a backup or dump so that you can blow everything out, do a fresh installation, and do a proper restore.